# Remove margins from PDFs

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, pdf-editor

I would like a software to edit Pdfs.

I have essentially margins on every page of the pdf I would like to take out before running it through OCR software. I would like to use free software.

They can not be programmatically removed to my knowledge.

Comment: Why do you need to remove margins if you are planning on running it through OCR software?  Once it's converted to text via OCR, margins are irrelevant.

Comment: The ocr is incorrectly rendering page creases and handwritten text in the margins as text.

Comment: So, you want margins to be removed at fixed distances, for instance 3 centimeters on the left, 2 centimeters at the top, etc, right? No automatic margin size detection, right?

Comment: @Nicholas yes that is correct

Answer (score 2):

[K2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) has the option to "remove margins" I just gave it a test works as expected

[image: B4]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Latest word will open PDF files for editing, think the online version through office365 will as well.  Or the Adobe Acrobat Pro version.

As far as programmatically, not sure on Windows but if the margins are consistent then pdftk can do it on a Linux system (hint - live disc or virtual machine)

Comment: How do you remove margins in word then?

Comment: https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/ PDFtk is available on Windows.

Comment: How about a way to convert them to pngs and then back to a pdf?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz that doesn't appear to let you do but a couple things like rotate the pdf and combine them

Comment: I have down voted this because the only requirement was to remove margins which your software doesn't do.

Comment: What Word version exactly? "Latest" is subject to change :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that DeftPDF has a [crop](https://deftpdf.com/crop-pdf) tool that can be used to crop specific parts of a PDF document. This means you can easily remove any unwanted areas from the document. Additionally, DeftPDF also has an OCR tool that can be used to recognize text in scanned documents or images, which could be useful to you after you crop the document. it's free to use! I hope this helps

disclosure: I'm a founder of DeftPDF.